# Threads in Background Service Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service, android-asynctask

Hi I am trying to use the service class for first time and have been facing problems. What I want is an infinitely running (unless killed by Android System) service with an active Network connection. I have written the code which works fine on Android 4.3 and 4.4 but the application crashes when I try running on Android 2.2. My code is as follows:

```
public class BackgroundMusicService extends Service {

private MediaPlayer mp;
private int id;

private static class BackgroundAsyncTaskClass extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Log.v("Async","Async Called");

                    /*Network connection will be created here*/

        return null;
    }
}

private class ForThread implements Runnable{
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Log.v("ThreadSleeping","5 sec");
                BackgroundAsyncTaskClass task = new BackgroundAsyncTaskClass();
                task.execute();
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }finally{
                Log.v("Finally called","Finally called");
            }   
        }
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.v("onStartCommand Called","onStart Command Called");

    Thread t;
    ForThread ft = new ForThread();
    t = new Thread(ft);
    t.start();

    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if(null != mp){
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
        Log.v("Destroyed","onDestroy Called");
    }
}

public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {

    Intent restartServiceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            this.getClass());
    restartServiceIntent.setPackage(getPackageName());

    PendingIntent restartServicePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
            getApplicationContext(), 1, restartServiceIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmService.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
            SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000,
            restartServicePendingIntent);

    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
}
```

}

and the exception thrown by Android 2.2 is as follows:

```
04-28 09:51:41.435: W/dalvikvm(280): threadid=7: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
04-28 09:51:41.435: E/AndroidRuntime(280): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-8
04-28 09:51:41.435: E/AndroidRuntime(280): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
04-28 09:51:41.435: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at com.example.backgroundservicedemo.BackgroundMusicService$ForThread.run(BackgroundMusicService.java:45)
04-28 09:51:41.435: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
04-28 09:51:41.435: E/AndroidRuntime(280): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
04-28 09:51:41.435: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
04-28 09:51:41.435: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.<init>(AsyncTask.java:421)
04-28 09:51:41.435: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.<init>(AsyncTask.java:421)
04-28 09:51:41.435: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.os.AsyncTask.<clinit>(AsyncTask.java:152)
```

Also, when I try using handler.post(new Runnable(){.... run(){}....} The UI hangs up but the background thread continues running and exits after it becomes out of memory.

Another thing that I have doubts about is:
When the application restarts, I want this active Service to stop, but how do I get a reference to this thread running in Background and how do I stop this? I would appreciate if anyone can redirect me to a suitable link/reference or could help me out with the code. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this inside a thread's run method

```
 BackgroundAsyncTaskClass task = new BackgroundAsyncTaskClass();
 task.execute();
```

Threading rules from the docs

1. **The AsyncTask class must be loaded on the UI thread**. This is done automatically as of JELLY_BEAN.
2. **The task instance must be created on the UI thread.
   execute(Params...) must be invoked on the UI thread.**
3. Do not call onPreExecute(), onPostExecute(Result), doInBackground(Params...), onProgressUpdate(Progress...) manually.
4. The task can be executed only once (an exception will be thrown if a second execution is attempted.)

Comment: That's nice. Reading the documentation is alway the first thing to do. Still it does not explain why execute() must called on the UI Thread.

Comment: @blackbelt right. will find a source to explain that.

Comment: @blackbelt the docs does not give details regarding the why part. If you know pls update my post. I am checking the source

Comment: I don't think you're even getting as far as execute().  It looks like the exception is from `new BackgroundAsyncTaskClass()`.  The reason is clear in the stack trace: something in your class or one of its superclasses is creating a Handler.

There is seldom a reason to use explicit threads or `Thread.sleep()` in Android.  You can usually replace them with the proper use of Handlers.

Comment: @kjkrum http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18705945/android-cant-create-handler-inside-thread-that-has-not-called-looper-prepare. Looks like calling execute in a background thread is the problem. But i am not able to answer the why part.

Comment: The why is "because it creates a Handler."

Comment: @kjkrum Handler is bound to the thread that created it. I already posted what was there in the docs. I also looked at the source code. But it would nice if some one could give a better explanation than my post

Comment: The thread that creates a Handler must be a Looper.  The UI thread is a Looper.  A thread created with `new Thread()` is not a Looper.

You can make a new Thread into a Looper, but you probably shouldn't.